# How to optimize speed of data loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a for-each in my views. let's say it does have 5000 data. so it take sometime to load the page. because those data are loaded to a data table in view. is there anyway to optimize and load them quickly??

In blade View

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<tr>
<td>{{$item->name}}</td>
...
...
...
</tr>
@endforeach
```

in controller

```
$items = Items::where('active',1)->get();
```

Comment: Just load the first n results and after that use ajax to load more if the user scrolls

Comment: 5000 data ! Who are willing to check all that data by scrolling . Just paginate my friend

Comment: If you use datatables.js library you can configure it to work with server side. So in that case it will send request for each page and fetches the limited part of data.
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be 3 ways you could follow (IMO)

1. Cache
2. Use pagination
3. Don't use Eloquent. Using just `DB::select` is much faster as Eloquent tends to use a lot of class or objects.

Answer (score 1):

**use laravel pagination:it will show 15 records per page**

```
$users =Items::where('active',1)->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have to use all result without pagination you could use :

```
$contents = View::make('view', compact('$items'))->render();
```

with this code, it will be buffering and showing the data after creating HTML code